# Reactjs material ui table with search filter handling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the react framework with material ui checkbox table - I would like to create a filter process so a person can click on the filter and a search box above appears allowing them to do a filter search on name for the entire results - and to be able to filter search the results on the fly on the frontend. I've tried to build the checkboxTable with the ability to add other actions and icons - like delete, bulk update type actions:

[image]

I am unsure if it is good ux to allow the user to choose which to column to filter with a dropdown - and input box:

[image]

Current sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-dirac-5kr92g?file=/src/components/_globals/CheckboxTable/CheckboxTable.scss

Code for the component is as follows.

Data for the component.

```
  let table = {
    header: "Patients",
    headCells: [
      {
        id: 'id',
        numeric: false,
        disablePadding: true,
        label: 'Id',
      },
      {
        id: 'name',
        numeric: false,
        disablePadding: true,
        label: 'Name (x)',
      },
      {
        id: 'saturation',
        numeric: true,
        disablePadding: false,
        label: 'Saturation (%)',
      },
    ],
    rows:[
      {id: '123', name: 'Tiffany Cruz', saturation: "10%"},
      {id: '124', name: 'Aaron Williams', saturation: "16%"},
      {id: '125', name: 'Estelie Balley', saturation: "30%"},
      {id: '126', name: 'Stephen Fries', saturation: "40%"},
      {id: '127', name: 'Jessica Alma', saturation: "2%"},
      {id: '128', name: 'Brian Pax', saturation: "3%"},
    ],
    otherActions: [      
      {
        "action": "filter",
        "icon" : <FilterListIcon />
      }
    ]
  }
```

The usage -- maybe rather then modify the checkboxTable component itself - could append a function that allows the filter - becoming its own component -- FilterCheckboxtable

```
<CheckboxTable data={table} handleAction={(action, selectedItems)=> console.log("data", action, selectedItems)} />
```

Current CheckboxTable

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import TableSortLabel from '@mui/material/TableSortLabel';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import FilterListIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FilterList';
import { visuallyHidden } from '@mui/utils';

import './CheckboxTable.scss';


function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
  return order === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

// Since 2020 all major browsers ensure sort stability with Array.prototype.sort().
// stableSort() brings sort stability to non-modern browsers (notably IE11). If you
// only support modern browsers you can replace stableSort(exampleArray, exampleComparator)
// with exampleArray.slice().sort(exampleComparator)
function stableSort(array, comparator) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) {
      return order;
    }
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
  const { onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, onRequestSort } =
    props;
  const createSortHandler = (newOrderBy) => (event) => {
    onRequestSort(event, newOrderBy);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            color="primary"
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{
              'aria-label': 'select all desserts',
            }}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {props.headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            className={"head-cell-"+headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? 'right' : 'left'}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'normal'}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <Box component="span" sx={visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === 'desc' ? 'sorted descending' : 'sorted ascending'}
                </Box>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  order: PropTypes.oneOf(['asc', 'desc']).isRequired,
  orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function EnhancedTableToolbar(props) {
  const { numSelected } = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      sx={{
        pl: { sm: 2 },
        pr: { xs: 1, sm: 1 },
        ...(numSelected > 0 && {
          bgcolor: (theme) =>
            alpha(theme.palette.primary.main, theme.palette.action.activatedOpacity),
        }),
      }}
    >
      {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <Typography
          sx={{ flex: '1 1 100%' }}
          color="inherit"
          variant="subtitle1"
          component="div"
        >
          {numSelected} selected
        </Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography
          sx={{ flex: '1 1 100%' }}
          variant="h6"
          id="tableTitle"
          component="div"
        >
          {props.header}
        </Typography>
      )}

      {
        console.log("xxxxxx props", props)
      }
      {
        //console.log("selected", props.selected)
      }

      {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <>
          {props.otherActions &&
             props.otherActions.map((item, j) => {
              return(
                <Tooltip key={j} title={item.label}>
                  <IconButton aria-label={item.action} onClick={(event) => props.handleAction(item.action, props.selected)}>
                    {item.icon}
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              )
            })
          }
        </>
      ) : (
        <Tooltip title="Filter list">
          <IconButton>
            <FilterListIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      )}

    </Toolbar>
  );
}

EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

export default function EnhancedTable(props) {
  //console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx------props", props)
  //console.log("yyyyyyyy------props.data.metaData", props.data.metaData)

  //metaData

  let DEFAULT_ORDER = 'asc';
  let DEFAULT_ORDER_BY = 'name';
  let DEFAULT_ROWS_PER_PAGE = 10;
  let DEFAULT_DENSE = true;

  if(props.data?.metaData){
    DEFAULT_ORDER = props.data.metaData.DEFAULT_ORDER;
    DEFAULT_ORDER_BY = props.data.metaData.DEFAULT_ORDER_BY;
    DEFAULT_ROWS_PER_PAGE = props.data.metaData.DEFAULT_ROWS_PER_PAGE;
    DEFAULT_DENSE = props.data.metaData.DEFAULT_DENSE;  
  }

  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState(DEFAULT_ORDER);
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState(DEFAULT_ORDER_BY);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [dense, setDense] = React.useState(DEFAULT_DENSE);
  const [visibleRows, setVisibleRows] = React.useState(null);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(DEFAULT_ROWS_PER_PAGE);
  const [paddingHeight, setPaddingHeight] = React.useState(0);

  let previousProps = React.useRef(props);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //////////////
    if(previousProps.data !== props.data) {
      //console.log("old", previousProps.data)
      setPage(0);//if the row length has changed..
      setSelected([]);
    }
    
    previousProps = props;
    ///////////

    let rowsOnMount = stableSort(
      props.data.rows,
      getComparator(DEFAULT_ORDER, DEFAULT_ORDER_BY),
    );

    rowsOnMount = rowsOnMount.slice(
      0 * DEFAULT_ROWS_PER_PAGE,
      0 * DEFAULT_ROWS_PER_PAGE + DEFAULT_ROWS_PER_PAGE,
    );

    setVisibleRows(rowsOnMount);
  }, [props]);

  const handleRequestSort = React.useCallback(
    (event, newOrderBy) => {
      const isAsc = orderBy === newOrderBy && order === 'asc';
      const toggledOrder = isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc';
      setOrder(toggledOrder);
      setOrderBy(newOrderBy);

      const sortedRows = stableSort(props.data.rows, getComparator(toggledOrder, newOrderBy));
      const updatedRows = sortedRows.slice(
        page * rowsPerPage,
        page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage,
      );

      setVisibleRows(updatedRows);
    },
    [order, orderBy, page, rowsPerPage, props],
  );

  const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelected = props.data.rows.map((n) => n.id);
      setSelected(newSelected);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };

  const handleClick = (event, id) => {
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }

    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const handleChangePage = React.useCallback(
    (event, newPage) => {
      setPage(newPage);

      const sortedRows = stableSort(props.data.rows, getComparator(order, orderBy));
      const updatedRows = sortedRows.slice(
        newPage * rowsPerPage,
        newPage * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage,
      );

      setVisibleRows(updatedRows);

      // Avoid a layout jump when reaching the last page with empty rows.
      const numEmptyRows =
        newPage > 0 ? Math.max(0, (1 + newPage) * rowsPerPage - props.data.rows.length) : 0;

      const newPaddingHeight = (dense ? 33 : 53) * numEmptyRows;
      setPaddingHeight(newPaddingHeight);
    },
    [order, orderBy, dense, rowsPerPage, props],
  );

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = React.useCallback(
    (event) => {
      const updatedRowsPerPage = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
      setRowsPerPage(updatedRowsPerPage);

      setPage(0);

      const sortedRows = stableSort(props.data.rows, getComparator(order, orderBy));
      const updatedRows = sortedRows.slice(
        0 * updatedRowsPerPage,
        0 * updatedRowsPerPage + updatedRowsPerPage,
      );

      setVisibleRows(updatedRows);

      // There is no layout jump to handle on the first page.
      setPaddingHeight(0);
    },
    [order, orderBy, props],
  );

  const handleChangeDense = (event) => {
    setDense(event.target.checked);
  };

  const isSelected = (id) => selected.indexOf(id) !== -1;

  const renderCells = (labelId, row) => {
    //console.log("xxxxxxxx---------row", row)

    let stack = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(row).length; ++i) {
      //console.log("xxx-", Object.keys(row)[i])

      if(i === 1){
        stack.push(<TableCell key={i} className={"cell-"+Object.keys(row)[i]} component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none">{row[Object.keys(row)[i]]}</TableCell>)
      } else {
        stack.push(<TableCell key={i} className={"cell-"+Object.keys(row)[i]} align="right">{row[Object.keys(row)[i]]}</TableCell>)
      }
    } 

    return stack;   
  }

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Paper sx={{ width: '100%', mb: 2 }}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar header={props.data.header} selected={selected} numSelected={selected.length} otherActions={props.data.otherActions} handleAction={props.handleAction} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className="checkbox-table"
            sx={{ minWidth: 750 }}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={dense ? 'small' : 'medium'}
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={props.data.rows.length}
              headCells={props.data.headCells}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {visibleRows
                ? visibleRows.map((row, index) => {
                    const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.id);
                    const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                    return (
                      <TableRow
                        hover
                        onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.id)}
                        role="checkbox"
                        aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                        tabIndex={-1}
                        key={row.id}
                        selected={isItemSelected}
                        sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                      >
                        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                          <Checkbox
                            color="primary"
                            checked={isItemSelected}
                            inputProps={{
                              'aria-labelledby': labelId,
                            }}
                          />
                        </TableCell>

                        {/*
                        <TableCell
                          component="th"
                          id={labelId}
                          scope="row"
                          padding="none"
                        >
                          {row.name}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                        */}
                        {
                          //console.log("row", row)
                        }
                        {
                          //console.log("key row", Object.keys(row))
                        }

                        {renderCells(labelId, row)}
                      </TableRow>
                    );
                  })
                : null}
              {paddingHeight > 0 && (
                <TableRow
                  style={{
                    height: paddingHeight,
                  }}
                >
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={props.data.rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={props.data.rows.length <= rowsPerPage? 0 : page}
          //page={!props.data.rows.length || props.data.rows.length <= 0 ? 0 : page}
          //page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />

      </Paper>
      {props.data?.metaData?.SWITCH_PADDING &&
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Switch checked={dense} onChange={handleChangeDense} />}
          label="Dense padding"
        />
      }
    </Box>
  );
}
```